# How to get desired color from base color in SASS

Tags: css, colors, sass, compass-sass

I want to have one base color and want to built dynamic color palate for my website so it becomes as easy to switch themes as changing a color value.

SASS has so many helper function which I believe enough to get me there. The problem I am facing here is in order to get to desired color value from that single base color, what function (or combination of functions) with what value shall I use.

There is this amazing tool http://sassme.arc90.com/ , which lets you play with various combinations but again you don't have full control over output.

For example If I have a base color `#ffe202` and I want output of `#ffd202`  I am not sure how to go about it, I can get somewhat closer by playing with controls but not exactly what I desire.

So bottom line is I was wondering if there is any tool where you input your base color and desired output color and it gives you combination of SASS helper functions to use similar to http://sassme.arc90.com/ .

Comment: Is it so important to use only one variable as a base color ? I believe this add complexity to your project.

Comment: @srekoble Well that's hypothetical. Bottom line is how may I get to know what and how to apply helper functions to get to desired colour from any given colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem, and built a tool that looks up functions that transition from one color to another. It suggests most commonly used ones, but may be applicable in your scenario. You still have to choose which function makes most sense, but at least it does the number crunching for you.

[image: Suggest SASS color function]

Comment: Thanks @alex-gyoshev . This perfect

Answer (score 0):

There's no strict way to always get a specific result from a given color, but you can just choose which of [Sass's color functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) you want to get the desired result.

In your case, your desired color just has a different green value from your starting color, so you can adjust the green thusly:

```
background-color: adjust-color($color, $green: -16);
```

[`adjust-color()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adjust_color-instance_method) will change just the green value. You can use positive or negative values to increase or decrease the amount of a hue; I landed on -16 through trial and error.

Comment: That's close, the actual reason I asked this question was to find any such tool. Trial and errors sometimes take so much time that it offsets the value of gain.

But now may be I can save much time.

Comment: @fusionstrings - Tool recommendations are off-topic; the best tool is rarely clear and changes over time. You're better off learning the features of the language to solve your problems.

Comment: Yup fair enough! Though I wasn't shying away from exploring / learning language but was searching for something to include in my workflow as many other tools.