# If I have the original color and a darkened color, how do I determine what percentage was used to darken it by in Sass?

Tags: colors, sass

Sass language has function called *darken* that takes two arguments: a color and percentage you want to darken the color by.  I only know the original color and the resulting color.  How can I determine the percentage value that was passed to the darken function along with the original color?

```
darken(#e8e8e8, ???) // returns #c1c1c1
```

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically define the % by which one color needs to be darkened to result in another color? Does it have to work with non-monochrome colors? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647881/how-to-get-desired-color-from-base-color-in-sass/24662251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For darken (and probably lighten too), you would want to calculate the difference between the lightness values of both colors:

```
@function color-difference($c1, $c2) {
  $c1: lightness($c1);
  $c2: lightness($c2);
  @return max($c1, $c2) - min($c1, $c2);
}

$color1: #e8e8e8;
$color2: #c1c1c1;

.foo {
  // guessed the percentage manually
  test: darken($color1, 15.25%);
  // check our percentage
  test: color-difference($color1, $color2);
  // do we get the same result?
  test: darken($color1, color-difference($color1, $color2));
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  test: #c1c1c1;
  test: 15.2941176471%;
  test: #c1c1c1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You  can use `rgba()`  where rgb is reg, green, blue and 'a' is alpha. You can use alpha instead of percentage.

Comment: I need a normal color without alpha